# how to store return value of a function in session array in php

Tags: php

```
$tsal[] = $obj->totalsal();

$_SESSION['totalsal'] = $tsal;

for($i=0; $i<count($tsal); $i++)
{
    echo $tsal[$i];
}
```

Is this the right way to store value that is returned from a function in an array using session?

Comment: function totalsal(){
      $tsal= $this->fsal()+$this->bonus();
      return $tsal;
       }this is my function and i am storing the return value $tsal as tsal[]=$obj->totalsal();

Comment: now i store the value of $tal as $_SESSION['totalsal']=$tsal;

Comment: but when i try to input new value the previous value does not get stored

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use session you have to always add [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Then you can access session variables.

If you want to iterate through array it is better to use `foreach` loop instead of `for`

Also this line `$tsal[]=$obj->totalsal();` creates something like this

```
$tsal = [0 => $obj->totalsal()];
```

It is pointless, just do: `$tsal = $obj->totalsal();`

```
$tsal = $obj->totalsal();

$_SESSION['totalsal'] = $tsal;

foreach ($tsal as $tsalElement) {
    echo $tsalElement;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use `$_SESSION` to store data in the PHP-session. However you need to first initialize/start the session in order to get this working. Use `start_session()` on top of every script you want to store/access session-data. For more infos look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)

```
<?php

session_start (); // now session data is available

$_SESSION['totalsal'] = $tsal;

...

?>
```

On some other script you can then access your data by

```
<?php

session_start ();

for ($i = 0; $i < count ($_SESSION['totalsal']); $i++)
    echo $_SESSION['totalsal'][$i];

...

?>
```

Comment: i am unable to get the output

Comment: @MeghaDholakia can you please more specific. what output do you not get?

Comment: function totalsal(){ $tsal= $this->fsal()+$this->bonus(); return $tsal; }this is my function and i am storing the return value $tsal as tsal[]=$obj->totalsal();

Comment: now i store the value of $tal as $_SESSION['totalsal']=$tsal;

Comment: but when i try to input new value the previous value does not get stored

Comment: @MeghaDholakia Of course, you most likly override your previouse value. use `$_SESSION['totalsal'][] = $tsal;` to store the new value by appending it to your session-variable. then you will have an array named `$_SESSION['totalsal']` with all your values saved

Comment: i have got an error  Cannot use a scalar value as an array